# How to get Date Added to Health in Healthkit

Tags: healthkit

I do not know how can i get the "Date Added to Health" ? I can not find some info about the "Date Added to Health" from HKSample.

Anyone can help me ?

```
HKSample : HKObject 
    open var sampleType: HKSampleType 
    open var startDate: Date 
    open var endDate: Date
```

Only has startDate & endDate, no has "Date Added to Health"

Answer (score 3):

There is no API in HealthKit to get the date a sample was added to Health. You should file a bug with Apple if you'd like this feature to be added.

Comment: A workaround could be to store a date as metadata when added.